# Using a perl script on windows without installing ActivePerl?

Tags: windows, perl, installation

I'm using Perl as my scripting language of choice under Windows and normally I just install [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) (mostly 5.8 for personal legacy reasons) and be done with it.

I now face the problem that I'd like to use some small scripts on a machine where I do not have any admin rights and therefore cannot install the ActiveState distribution with its installer.

What needs to be zipped together from an installed ActiveState Perl to do an xcopy-style installation of Perl on Windows? (And which environment variables will then have to be set in a command shell to make it work?)

Comment: In addition to just copy xcopy style, you may need to register perl's dlls with the new system so that the executable can find them, maybe couple of reg entries as well - so you need to experiment and figure out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) has a portable edition. I'd use that in preference to trying to hack ActivePerl into working without being properly installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can install ActivePerl without admin rights by using the *.zip file installer instead of the *.msi.  Download from the [ActivePerl 5.26.3 download directory](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePerl/releases/5.26.3.2603/) and run the `installer.bat` file in the root of the extracted tree.

Comment: Thanks! Useful info! I have not tried it, but note that the ZIP installer will not run through without (at least) warnings, because it will try to create registry keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and other stuff the msi installer also tries to do -- which cannot work if you are not admin.

Comment: I guess this message from the batch installer says it all:     *This installer can install $product in any location of your choice.
    You do not need Administrator privileges.  However, please make sure
    that you have write access to this location.*

Comment: This works. Download the zip. Extract. Add the /bin directory to your path. You're done.

Answer (score 3):

[`PAR::Packer`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PAR%3a%3aPacker) allows you to pack `perl` along with your scripts and modules it depends on in a standalone executable. You might want to double-check ActiveState's license terms to make sure this type of distribution is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Strawberry Perl from [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869118/using-a-perl-script-on-windows-without-installing-activeperl/5869154#5869154) might be the best solution as it officially supports xcopy installation.

However, I have now just tried copying the installation directory `C:\Perl` of ActiveState and when `C:\Perl\bin` is added to `PATH` it seems to execute my script(s) just fine.

Obviously, you have to run scripts via `__> perl file.pl` as no file association exists for Windows to know how to call just `__> file.pl` as it would when using the installed version, but you always have to do that with xcopy-installs.

I have also inspected the MSI installer from ActiveState (for 5.8) and it only contains files that are installed to `TARGETDIR\Perl` so I think just copying the Perl directory should also be safe for ActiveState.

Answer (score 0):

From what I hear, ActivePerl can be tricky to handle this way.. however, I found this at perlmonks:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Portable%20perl%3A%20usb%20thumbdrive

In short: Guy wants perl on windows without admin rights, so he makes a usb thumbdrive that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link where you can get portable perl edition. 
http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html

Here are some Explanatory Notes from the page where you can fine different installation files. e.g MSI, ZIP etc

MSI installer = preferred way, requires admin privileges to install

ZIP edition = admin privileges not required, however you need to run some post-install scripts manually after unzip

PortableZIP edition = suitable for "perl on USB stick" (you can move/rename the perl directory and it will still work)

MSM merge module = for advanced users who want to build their own MSI based on Strawberry Perl

DDrive edition = (not used since 5.12 series) special edition with fixed install path to d:\strawberry